# stunnel - two Ubuntu machines traffic encryption

Tags: encryption, stunnel

I have a problem getting Stunnel to work on Ubuntu 18.04. There are tons of websites that tell how to configure it but nothing works with me, I guess I am doing something wrong.

Here are the steps I did:

OS: Ubuntu18.04 (virtual machine, clean install)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install stunnel4
```

Then enable auto startup by:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/stunnel4
```

Switch ENABLE=0 to ENABLE=1

Next step is create a certification file by:

```
sudo openssl req -new -out config.pem -keyout config.pem -nodes -x509 -days 365
```

The location of certification file is: /etc/stunnel/

Then create a configuration file, here is a copy for the one I created:

[image: configuration file sample]

All set, restarting the service is the last step.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/stunnel4 restart
```

and here I got the following error :

*[....] Restarting stunnel4 (via systemctl): stunnel4.serviceJob for stunnel4.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status stunnel4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!*

(I am looking to encrypt the traffic between two Ubuntu machines)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What "traffic" is it exactly that you want to encrypt "between the two ubuntu machines"?

Comment: Have you tried `See "systemctl status stunnel4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`? Maybe it will even show an error to point into the direction where the error could lie.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install stunnel on both machines i.e server and client

`sudo apt-get install stunnel`

Once apt-get has finished we will need to enable stunnel by editing the /etc/default/stunnel4 configuration file in both client and server.

Find:

Change to one to enable stunnel automatic startup
`ENABLED=0`

Replace:

Change to one to enable stunnel automatic startup
`ENABLED=1`

2 . Install tinyproxy on server --> This is just a proxy server in my case i used custom one.

`sudo apt-get install tinyproxy`

**Configuring tinyproxy**

By default TinyProxy starts up listening on all interfaces for a connection to port 8888. Since we don’t want to leave our proxy open to the world, let’s change this by configuring TinyProxy to listen to the localhost interface only. We can do this by modifying the Listen parameter within the /etc/tinyproxy.conf file.

Find:

`#Listen 192.168.0.1`

Replace With:

`Listen 127.0.0.1`

Once complete, we will need to restart the TinyProxy service in order for our change to take effect. We can do this using the systemctl command.

`server: $ sudo systemctl restart tinyproxy`

After systemctl completes, we can validate that our change is in place by checking whether port 8888 is bound correctly using the netstat command.

```
server: $ netstat -na
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

3. Create certificate using openssl on server

Easier way:

```
            (a). openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048

            (b). openssl req -new -x509 -key key.pem -out cert.pem -days 1095

            (c).  cat key.pem cert.pem >> /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
```

You can opt to do (c) manually

Also remember to transfer the certificate to the client machine also...so both client and server have  */etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem*

**Stunnel server settings**

```
cert = stunnel.pem
[tinyproxy]
accept = 0.0.0.0:3112
connect = 127.0.0.1:8888
```

**Stunnel Client settings**

```
cert = stunnel.pem
client = yes
[tinyproxy]
accept = 127.0.0.1:3112
connect = 10.0.2.15:3112
```

**Assuming your using virtualbox which has your ubuntu server installed there you have to do the following settings**

In `Settings>>Network` change the adpater to **NAT**

Then in `Settings>>Network>>advanced>>port fowarding`  add port fowarding

```
*Name*      *Protocol*  *Host IP*   *Host port*     *Guest IP*   *Guest port*
stunnel           TCP        0.0.0.0        3112                    3112
```

**Once your done restart Services**

In client

`sudo systemctl restart stunnel4.service`

In server

`sudo systemctl restart stunnel4.service`

`sudo systemctl restart tinyproxy`

**To test if it worked**

In terminal:

`export http_proxy="http://localhost:3112"`

`export https_proxy="https://localhost:3112`

then:

`curl --proxy-insecure -v https://www.google.com`

## Credit:

https://bencane.com/2017/04/15/using-stunnel-and-tinyproxy-to-hide-http-traffic/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ssl-tunnel-using-stunnel-on-ubuntu